# How do I join text if key value are the same

Tags: python

my code

```
import requests

request = requests.get("https://itspaudal-git.github.io/jsonapi/roku.json")
package_json = request.json()

menu = package_json['Chicago']['Menu']['Strawberry Pie']
for i in menu:
    product = i['item'] 
    weight = i['weight']
    uom = i['uom']
    container2products = {}
    for j in i['tags']:
        container = j['container']
        container2products.setdefault(container,[])
        container2products[container].append(product)
    for container, products_list in container2products.items():
        products_str = '&'.join(products_list)
        print(products_str, container)
```

I was wondering if someone could point to me the right direction how to concatenate if key values are the same. My current output is

```
Whipping Cream 1 oz cup
Water tray 1
Cornstarch tray 1
Sugar 1 oz cup
fresh strawberries 20 oz cup
```

and I want it to be

```
Whipping Cream & Sugar 1 oz cup
Water & Constarch tray 1
fresh stawberries 20 oz cup
```

Comment: Just from a usability point of view, are you aware that a 1oz cup of cream and sugar is half the amount of 1oz of cream and 1oz of sugar?

Comment: Make a dictionary where the container is the key. Detect and handle collisions using your custom rules here, i.e. just join the strings with ' & '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a nfew changes to your code and also added some comment for undertsanding.
We are using a dictionary to store values instead of simple lists.
Hope it helps.

```
import requests

request = requests.get("https://itspaudal-git.github.io/jsonapi/roku.json")
package_json = request.json()

#This is dictionaru used to store items and thier quantities
items = {}
menu = package_json['Chicago']['Menu']['Strawberry Pie']
for i in menu:
    product = i['item'] 
    weight = i['weight']
    uom = i['uom']
    container2products = {}
    for j in i['tags']:
        container = j['container']
            #add item in same key if present
        if container in items:
            items[container] = items[container] + [product]
        else:
            #add item in new key if not present
            items[container] = [product]
            
#looping though the product quantities
for key in items:
    print(" & ".join(items[key]), key)
```